Wine fridge compressor wont restart after unplugging
Have wine fridge, wasnt keeping temp. The compressor kept heating up and shutting down. I started it with 2 cases of room temp bottled water in it last night at 22°c, and its been bumping around between 13 and 10 today.  I Assumed it was low on coolant.
Unplugged to install bullet valve on low side to check pressure and possibly recharge 134a, but when plugged back in compressor wont restart. Its been about 40 minutes.
Its not hot.  I put a multimeter on the thermostat cooling contacts and 119v is going to compressor..
I didnt tip it more than 30° for 10 seconds to get a dolly under it.  What gives?  Any tips?
Thank you
Paula

Brand/model? When you say you installed a bullet valve on the low side, did you actually open up the coolant lines to install a new valve or did you install the valve by threading something on to an existing fitting? Please feel free to [edit] to use full words, they're pretty cheap these days and make things much easier to read. Also, some apostrophes in contractions are good, too. I mean "wont" is a word, but I think you mean "won't"...

Compressor restarted. For the sake of anyone who comes across this post later I replaced the original thermostat that only went down to 45 degrees F with an
STC-1000 thermostat- which defaults to 10° C setting.... with a 3° differential-  i knew it was a 10 degree setting and the wiring was functional so I didnt bother to lower the setting...  so my compressor was never going to start at 12 degrees C and change. The thermostat comes programed with a 3° C differential- so rather than. Thermostat that turns on and off at a specific temp- this turns on and off at 3* higher or lower.   This is 6 degrees F on either end- so 12 total, between shutting down and turning back on...thats way too many. seems ridiculous to me- but its how it works.  I was able to set the differential to 1°c, and now it operates as I hoped.
This is why you should always RTFM.. read the -blanking- manual.

Wine enthusiast model wbs-133CD.
Im- excuse me I'M-  not sure what about "installed a bullet valve on the low side" is confusing.
A bullet valve is a self piercing valve used to access a closed refrigeration system. You install on the low pressure/refridergant return side in order to attach pressure guages and/or refrigerant dispensing hoses.
Problem is, the compressor didnt restart even though it was cool.  You cant properly get a operating pressure reading or recharge the system if the compressor isnt operating.
I know the thermostat is working properly and that the compressor came on at some point durring the night, after my initial post,  since it was hot this morning and the temp inside had dropped, but it cut out again (due to overheating) by the time I woke up.
Im trying to figure out why restoring power, even after the compressor cools, doesnt restart the compressor-  it does start at some later time- but I cant, excuse me can't- I know that apostrophe is very important to get my point across- I can not determine why the delay or how long it is...
It almost certainly needs refrigerant, but the compressor has to be running and  I can not spend the whole day watching and waiting. What can I do? or can anyone help me understand why it doesnt restart right away, how long te delay might be, what is causing it... so I can catch it running to properly test the pressue and refill.
Thank you for your useful correction on the use of apostrophes. Your welcome for my explanation of bullet valves.

This should be edited back into the question
